# Apple Configurator 2 - How to edit an installed Configuration Profile?

Tags: apple-configurator

I wish to modify an existing Configuration Profile installed on an iPhone, but I do not have a disk copy of it, nor can I download it again from the source (no longer available).  Using Apple Configurator 2 there appears to be no way to export to disk, or modify, the full contents of an already existing and installed Configuration Profile.  Nor indeed to inspect its contents (which would provide a tedious but manual way to re-create a new profile by inspecting the contents of an existing one)

Is there a way of extracting an installed Configuration Profile from an iDevice to disk so that I can then open it and modify it using Configurator?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this. The device doesn't keep the complete profile around.

Comment: Do you have an authoritative source for that?